# UITextField triggers unwanted segue when keyboard is dismissed

Tags: ios, keyboard, storyboard, uitextfield, segue

I'm using Storyboard with this project and have a UITextField inside a view. The user is able to type in a search term, press return and a segue to a resultsViewController occurs as intended.

The problem I am having is that if for any reason the keyboard gets dismissed, the segue occurs automatically. For example, if the user taps the iPad's drop keyboard key, the segue occurs without a search term... or if the user taps outside the UITextField, the keyboard drops (as intended), but the segue also occurs (not intended).

Here's are the methods I'm using (the UITextField's delegate is set in storyboard); also, I've put in "resignFirstResponder" and "endEditing: YES" messages in several places as I was trying to figure out a solution. Sorry for the mess:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

  if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
  }

  self.clueString = textField.text;
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;

}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

  [self.view resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;

}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

 [self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

Comment: what is your segue connected to?

Comment: The segue is wired in storyboard. The line goes from UITextField to resultsViewController, and it is a push.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I feel silly but I'll answer my question in case anyone else has this problem.

To control when the segue should or should not occur, I needed to implement the following method:

```
-(BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
if ([self.searchField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return NO;
    }
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please accept this answer (even though you answered it yourself) so that people who come here in the future know what the "correct" answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this method to always return no? You might need to have a check in there on whether or not to search. (Like your above method)

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

[self.view resignFirstResponder];
return YES;

}
```

Comment: Returning NO prevents the keyboard from dropping. I just want the keyboard to drop without segue-ing. The segue should be performed only when there is text in the field.